# AngularJS $filter for nested fields does not work as expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I want to filter my shop objects according to their name. But "name" field is nested like:

```
name: {
    "en": "name english",
    "tr": "name turkish"
}
```

and params.filter() is : 
    name.en:"eng"

If I filter like that:

```
$filter('filter')($scope.shops, params.filter())
```

result is an empty array.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Angular's filter operates on arrays, not objects.  To do what you need, so long as you are doing in javascript, can be done like this

`$scope.shops[params.filter()];`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your syntax is not correct, try doing something like this.

$filter('filter')($scope.shops, {name: en})[0];

This should return the first value in your object.

Comment: But what I need is search in name.en field.